# Main differences between registry and file_registry tables in Drupal SQL tables structure?

Tags: database

I already know that in computing in general, registry is the main data structure for paths (whether as a table in DB or a as a standalone DB).

In the case of Drupal, I saw two tables in the DB's. When is "registry" and the second is "file_registry".

While I understand that file_registry table holds paths for files, I wonder what are the main kinds of paths that the "general" registry table holds, and thus what are the main differences between them. I hope a Drupal developer who have dived into these SQL files could explain the main differences,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file_registry` stores entries for all uploaded files as `attachments` or `file_entities` to Drupal. Files marked for deletetion are removed at Cron and cleared from the table.

The `registry` table stores Drupal system information on all available code files available to the system from `modules` and `themes`. And more importantly includes all php `classes` used in the system and where they may be found. When you install or remove modules or themes from your Drupal installation php files are added/removed from the `registry` table.

Comment: You're thinking of `file_managed` with the first paragraph...OP has actually spelt it wrong, they meant `registry_file`, which is something different

Comment: ah, you're right .... where's my caffeine.

Comment: @tenken, in your last sentence, did you mean to say (paths for) php files are...? Thanks,